# Redirect only default.aspx on the root folder web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

http://foo.com/Default.aspx

http://foo.com/about/Default.aspx

http://foo.com/random/Default.aspx

```
                <rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true"> 
                  <match url="(.*)default.aspx" /> 
                  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
                </rule>
```

This redirects all the /Default.aspx to /

I only need the Default.aspx on the root to redirect to /. How can that be done? TIA

Answer (score 1):

Finally, was able to get it working.

```
            <rule name="root home" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
                <match url="Default.aspx" ignoreCase="true"  /> 
                <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
            </rule>
```

patternSyntax="ExactMatch" was what was needed to fix the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the domain name in the regex instead of (.*)

```
<rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true"> 
              <match url="(.*)foo.com/default.aspx" /> 
              <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}foo.com" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
            </rule>
```

[image: foo.com/default.aspx regex test results]

Comment: thanks but it didnt work. the following worked fine. This is a redirect to mobile default.aspx to root.

<rule name="root homemobile" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^mobile/Default.aspx" ignoreCase="true" />
     <action type="Redirect" url="/mobile/" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>

but to the actual root of the site, it is not working.

Comment: You should be able to do the mobile directory like this

<rule name="root homemobile" stopProcessing="true"> 
<match url="(.*)/mobile/Default.aspx" ignoreCase="true" /> 
<action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/mobile/" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
</rule>

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, these didn't work for me

Comment: **Test Pattern** ? tool ?